# Filtering output of Get-Command

Tags: powershell

I am a powershell novice and find myself constantly using `Get-Command <cmdlet> -syntax` to learn more about parameters. My questions is how can I filter the output of `Get-Command Set-ADUser -syntax` for specific strings?

I attempted to pipe `Where-Object` and `filter`, but am not having any luck.

Comment: You'll get everything back as one big honkin' string, so all you need to do to further process that is split it, e.g. `(Get-Command Get-Command -Syntax).Split("`r`n") | Select-String verb`.

Comment: You're right about getting everything back as one string. I didn't think about that. Thanks for the help. Running `Get-Command Set-ADUser -Syntax.Split("r n") | Select-String Office` returns matches! Might I ask what is the significance of the `"r n"` line in split?

Comment: Ouch, forgot the escaping rules of SO. Of course I meant ``.Split("`r`n")``, using the backtick to escape special characters in PowerShell. The intent is to split on newline. (On second thought perhaps using `[Environment]::NewLine` would be easier, and possibly more portable now that PowerShell on Linux is a thing.

Comment: Thanks again. Environment is much easier to use. I do appreciate the explanation and assistance.

Comment: As for [possibly more portable now that PowerShell on Linux is a thing.], this... ["`r`n"], is just RegEx. So, not a PowerShell only thing, regardless of OS.

Comment: @postanote: Nope -- I used `String.Split`, which doesn't use a regex. `-split` does, but I like to avoid the use of a regex for trivial cases like this (especially since the escape rules aren't the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just part of a 'Mastering PowerShell Help' file I give folks who attend my Automation classes/sessions/engagements. Maybe it will aid you.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Set-ADUser).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Set-ADUser).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Set-ADUser -Examples
Get-help -Name Set-ADUser -Full
Get-help -Name Set-ADUser -Online

# Find all cmdlets / functions with a target parameter
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet |
Where-Object {
    Try {$PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'credential'}
    Catch{} 
}|
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title '
Available cmdlets which have a specific parameter'

Get-Command -CommandType Function |
Where-Object {
    Try {$PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'credential'}
    Catch{} 
}|
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title '
Available functions which have a specific parameter'

# Get property enums/options for a specifc cmdlet/function
(Get-Service | Select-Object -First 1).Status.GetType()
[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::
GetNames([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus])
```

Why do this...

```
Get-Command Set-ADUser -Syntax
```

... vs this...

```
(Get-Command -Name Set-ADUser).Parameters.Keys | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select an item to view its properties and methods'| 
Get-Member -Force | 
Out-GridView
```

(OGV allows for real-time filtering.)

..or just doing this

```
Show-Command -Name Set-ADUser
```

If you are in the ISE just use the Commands tab and double click the command of interest, vs messing with raw text.
If you are in VSCode, choose the Command Explorer and double click the command of interest, then click the help icon, vs messing with raw text.

Yet, if you just want to stay in the console host and use text, then this...

```
<#
List of all parameters that a given cmdlet supports along with a short 
description:
#>
Get-Help Set-ADUser -para '*' | 
Format-Table Name, { $PSItem.Description[0].Text } -wrap 

Get-Help Set-ADUser -para '*' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match 'Office' | 
Format-Table Name, { $PSItem.Description[0].Text } -wrap
```

Use OGV for real-time filtering and selection,  but get results in console text.

```
Get-Help Set-ADUser -para '*' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match ((Get-Command -Name Set-ADUser).Parameters.Keys | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select an item to view its syntax details') | 
Format-Table Name, { $PSItem.Description[0].Text } -wrap
```

***Update***

As per your comment...

> how could I add another column for the parameter's variable type?
> Looking at the example of office, how could I add a column that would
> contain

... you could do this.

```
Get-Help Set-ADUser -Parameter '*' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match ((Get-Command -Name Set-ADUser).Parameters.Keys | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select an item to view its syntax details') | 
ForEach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name        = $PSItem.Name
        Type        = $PSItem.Type.Name
        Description = $PSItem.Description[0].Text
    }
} | 
Format-Table Name, Type, Description -wrap

# Results
<#
Name        Type   Description                                                                                                                               
----        ----   -----------                                                                                                                               
Office      String Specifies the location of the user's office or place of business. This parameter sets the Office property of a user object. The LDAP      
                   display name (ldapDisplayName) of this property is "office".                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                         
OfficePhone String Specifies the user's office telephone number. This parameter sets the OfficePhone property of a user object. The LDAP display name        
                   (ldapDisplayName) of this property is "telephoneNumber".   
#>
```

Comment: Everything looks great. I never considered using OGV for filtering. On your OGV filtering and display in console, I think you forgot a `|` near details.

Comment: Yeppers, forgot that pipe when pasting (fixed), but I'm old and it happens. ;-} , you know OPP (old people problems).

Comment: I like the grid view, but how could I add another column for the parameter's variable type? Looking at the example of office, how could I add a column that would contain `<string>`?

Comment: Add a call to the other items of interest to the Select process, similar to the calculated property I am showing thus far.